# Can for-loops counter be const declaration in ES2015?

Tags: javascript, for-loop, ecmascript-6

First, `let` can be used on loop counter declaration. This is also [described in MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/let#Cleaner_code_in_inner_functions).

```
for(let i = 0; i < 2; ++i) {
  setTimeout(function(){
    document.write(i + "<br>");
  }, 0);
}
```

result:

```
0
1
```

Since `let` is used, a value of `i` can be changed in inside of `for` block.

```
for(let i = 0; i < 2; ++i) {
  setTimeout(function(){
    document.write(i + "<br>");
  }, 0);
  i = 123; // I want to block this assignment!!
}
```

So I considered using `const` instead of `let`.

```
for(const i = 0; i < 2; ++i) { // throws Assignment to constant variable
  setTimeout(function(){
    document.write(i + "<br>");
  }, 0);
  i = 123; // not here...
}
```

However, this code throws `Assignment to constant variable.` (in Chrome 53.0.2773.0).

I expected this loops twice like first `let` example, but make counter `i` writable in internal for-loop iteration only.

I think this is allowed because [ECMA-262 §13.7.4.7](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/#sec-for-statement-runtime-semantics-labelledevaluation) seems to mention this situation as *If isConst is true, ...*, but I cannot find this usage (or implementation status) in MDN and other sites. Kangax's table contains tests for [`let` bindings](https://kangax.github.io/compat-table/es6/#test-let_for/for-in_loop_iteration_scope), but not for `const` bindings.

Comment: const won't work in for loop because you are changing the value of a constant  in loop (++i) which is not allowed.

Comment: Uh, Kangax' table [*does* contain a row about it](https://kangax.github.io/compat-table/es6/#test-const_for_loop_statement_scope), and Chrome does support it, but `++i` should throw an exception. What exactly do you mean by "*code is not working*", what happens?

Comment: This seems like something that could easily be addressed via a linter rule.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I tested it (in Firefox) and the const binding works according to spec:

```js
let i = 0;
for (const len = 3; i < len; i++) {
  console.log(i);
}

// From https://kangax.github.io/compat-table/es6/#test-const
for (const baz = 0; false;) {}

// Yay, a const counter! ...uh
for (const counter = {i: 0}; counter.i < 3; counter.i++) {
  console.log(counter.i);
}
```

It is probably not particularly useful though...

**Why does it work?**
The [standard](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/#sec-for-statement-runtime-semantics-labelledevaluation) says:

```
  5. For each element dn of boundNames do
    a. If isConst is true, then
      i.  Perform loopEnv.CreateImmutableBinding(dn, true).
```

...where `boundNames` refers to the `const` binding. As you can see, the standard allows `const` 'loop counters', but doesn't say that you will be able to re-assign (increment) them later on (which, in fact, does not work).